# How to Convert String type date to date for entry into oracle DB - Java

Tags: java, string, date-format

Incoming date format id 2014-11-03 00.00.00.0 and need to be converted to either 03/11/2014 or 03-Nov-2014.

What could be the best possible and smallest code?

Comment: Why convert it to a string at all and not just a `java.sql.Date` instance?

Comment: It would be better if you were using ORM, or even prepared statements where you can set a date object directly. Anyway, an input date that is coming as a string from a third party can be parsed as a date using a SimpleDateFormat with format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss.t'

Comment: @Mureinik Actually, I am setting the date from the DB to a JSP form and then again retrieving it to set it in another table and while supplying the date as "2014-11-03 00.00.00.0", DB restricts it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so you have a `String` with the value  `2014-11-03 00.00.00.0` and you want to insert that value in a `DATE` field inside a Oracle Database Table, using Java's JDBC?

Well, first, convert that `String` into a `Date` object using a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object:

```
String s = "2014-11-03 00.00.00.0";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.S").parse(s);
```

Then, if you are using plain statements, reformat it the way Oracle would accept it in an `SQL INSERT` command, using again a `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
String sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(d);
```

and insert it into your Statement:

```
cn.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE(...) VALUES(" + sd + ");
```

I would recommend you to better use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of a plain `SQL INSERT` statement so your statement is sanitized:

```
PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
```

And then, insert your date as a Date object without the need of formatting into a String:

```
ps.setDate([index of the field to insert], d);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using java 8 there's a very useful date format class `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`
With that class you can do something like these:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
String text = date.format(formatter);
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);

DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/DD/YYYY");
String newText = parsedDate.format(formatter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 getting a `java.sql.Date` (= `java.util.Date` with zero time) from that string may use a formatter, but as the string is almost ISO standard:

```
    LocalDateTime x = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-11-03T00:00:00.0");
```

one could patch the string as:

```
    LocalDateTime t = LocalDateTime.parse("2014-11-03 00.00.00.0"
            .replaceFirst(" ", "T") // Make ISO
            .replaceFirst("\\.", ":")
            .replaceFirst("\\.", ":"));

    java.sql.Date time = java.sql.Date.valueOf(t.toLocalDate());
```

Or

```
    LocalDate t = LocalDate.parse("2014-11-03 00.00.00.0"
            .replaceFirst(" .*$", "")); // Remove time part
    java.sql.Date time = java.sql.Date.valueOf(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDate.parse(  "2014-11-03 00.00.00.0".substring( 0 , 10 ) ) 
);
```

> What could be the best possible and smallest code?

There you go. But I do *not* recommend actually crunching so much into a single line. The “best” code is rarely the “smallest” code.

## Details

Other answers are correct. But here is something shorter.

First of all, you should not be submitting a date-only value to a database as a string. Submit as a date-only object. Your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) will handle the details of communicating that to the database.

First extract your date value by calling [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-). With padding zeros on month and day-of-month we know the first 10 digits are the date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(  "2014-11-03 00.00.00.0".substring( 0 , 10 ) );
```

If your JDBC driver complies with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) or later, you can pass the `LocalDate` directly via [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-int-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld );
```

…or perhaps:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld , JDBCType.DATE );
```

If your driver does not comply, convert to the legacy class [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). Look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld );
```

The approach described here assumes the input string was intended for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If not, you need to adjust into UTC. Search Stack Overflow for posts on parsing a string as a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me. a small utility method to generate a string value of a date that can be inserted into an Oracle Database Date Field, abit dirty but works.
first function uses Calender class and second one LocalDate ( Java8 or higher )

1.

```
      /*
     * Format Date for Presentation in format
     * 19-DEC-2019   i.e. Oracle DB DD-MMM-YYYYY
     */
    private String stringToDate(String inputDate) {
        String finalDate = null;
        if (inputDate == null)
            return null;

        try {
            Date parseDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(inputDate);

            // set your local time zone
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Lusaka"));
            cal.setTime(parseDate);
            String finalMonth = "";
            int yearVal = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int monthVal = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);  //returns value 0 to 11
            int dayVal = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            switch(monthVal) {
            case 0:
                finalMonth = "JAN";
                break;
            case 1:
                finalMonth = "FEB";
                break;
            case 2:
                finalMonth = "MAR";
                break;
            case 3:
                finalMonth = "APR";
                break;
            case 4:
                finalMonth = "MAY";
                break;
            case 5:
                finalMonth = "JUN";
                break;
            case 6:
                finalMonth = "JUL";
                break;
            case 7:
                finalMonth = "AUG";
                break;
            case 8:
                finalMonth = "SEP";
                break;
            case 9:
                finalMonth = "OCT";
                break;
            case 10:
                finalMonth = "NOV";
                break;
            case 11:
                finalMonth = "DEC";
                break;

            }

            finalDate = dayVal+"-"+finalMonth+"-"+yearVal;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return finalDate;
    }
```

2.

```
       /*
     * Format Date for Presentation in format
     *  19-DEC-2019   i.e. Oracle DB DD-MMM-YYYYY
     */
    private String stringToDateJava8(String inputDate) {
        String finalDate = null;
        if (inputDate == null)
            return null;

        try {
            Date parseDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(inputDate);

            String finalMonth = "";
            LocalDate localDate = parseDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            int yearVal  = localDate.getYear();
            int monthVal = localDate.getMonthValue();   //returns value 1 to 12
            int dayVal   = localDate.getDayOfMonth();

            switch(monthVal) {
            case 1:
                finalMonth = "JAN";
                break;
            case 2:
                finalMonth = "FEB";
                break;
            case 3:
                finalMonth = "MAR";
                break;
            case 4:
                finalMonth = "APR";
                break;
            case 5:
                finalMonth = "MAY";
                break;
            case 6:
                finalMonth = "JUN";
                break;
            case 7:
                finalMonth = "JUL";
                break;
            case 8:
                finalMonth = "AUG";
                break;
            case 9:
                finalMonth = "SEP";
                break;
            case 10:
                finalMonth = "OCT";
                break;
            case 11:
                finalMonth = "NOV";
                break;
            case 12:
                finalMonth = "DEC";
                break;

            }

            finalDate = dayVal+"-"+finalMonth+"-"+yearVal;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return finalDate;
    }
```